# How to create this 3d rotation in jQuery? Is this possible?

Tags: jquery

I made an example in Flash, but is this possible with jQuery? I know its possible but with css3, but i want internet explorer support.

Can't find the right jquery plugin.

Can anyone help? thanks.

http://philiphannaart.nl/rotate/test.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no evidence of research or individual effort.

Comment: Internet Explorer can handle this; it's just a rotate and perspective. Older versions of IE won't be able to handle it, but they can animate the height up from zero, which is *similar*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular animation is simple enough that all modern browsers, [including Internet Explorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/02/02/css3-3d-transforms-in-ie10.aspx), can handle it. Essentially, you're just modifying the [`rotatex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj127312%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) value on an element over time:

```css
.stackoverflow {
    perspective: 500px;
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    animation: standup 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes standup {
    to { transform: rotateX(0); }
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KbIGa

The [`perspective` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772272%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will give the image depth. This will work in IE10+. Internet Explorer 9 will require the `-ms-` prefix (or use [prefixfree](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/)). Prior to IE9 you can simply animate the height of the image as a potential fallback:

```html
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".stackoverflow").animate({ height: "128px" }, 1000);
        });
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

The above lumps IE9 and all versions below into the same group, and animates the `.stackoverflow` image via jQuery/JavaScript.

Comment: You sir. Are my hero. Thanks a lot!